# Vertical task menu list

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lenovo

I was playing with settings or something and I changed my menu task list to be in horizontal style. Earlier it was in vertical style. How can I change it back in lenovo k4 note (marshmallow).

I want it to be like this:

[image]